# Alter Access Field Formats

Tags: ms-access

I have a field that is formatted as a short date. When the field is empty, how do I get text to appear in the field as guidance? For example, I want the field to read "DATE RECEIVED" when empty, but, when completed force a short date entry.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the *Format* property of the textbox displaying the value to:

```
yyyy-mm-dd;;;"DATE RECEIVED"
```